# Xamarin android API automatic change

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

There is an issue for me with VS 2017 and Xamarin.

Whenever I choose 7.0 android API VS compiles it by itself into 8.1.

It is really annoying because when I change it manually to 7.0 there are errors that i cannot fix.

Have anyone had this problem and knows how to make it compiles to version i want without creating it into 8.1?

Comment: What errors are you getting with 7.0?  Please add them to your question

Comment: main thing i want to achieve is to load my project with max API 7.0 android like i can do it in android studio. Unfortunately in work i have to work in visual on c# and i have hard time to get things together. i can only select at start min SDK but lowering higher is not working as i want it to

Comment: Have you checked in Tools->Android->Android SDK Manager that you have the correct SDK platform for 7.0?